# How can I refactor and DRY out "user checking" code in my controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Still learning the ropes, so I'm barely past the basics with .Net and C#.

In many (but not all) of my controllers, I have this same bit of code used to determine if the user is valid and can access the page.

```cs
public IActionResult MyPage(string id = null)
{
    if (_currentUser == null) {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }

    // Either the parameter value or a session variable.
    id = id ?? _currentUser.UserEmployeeNumber; 

    Employee employee = _employeeRepository.GetEmployeeById(id);

    if (employee == null) {
       return RedirectToAction("Error", "Team");
    }

    if (!_userChecks.IsAllowedAccess(_currentUser.UserEmployeeNumber, id)){
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Home");
    }

    // Begin actual page functionality

    return View(myPageViewModel);
}
```

How might I extract this out and make it reusable? Perhaps with an end goal similar to:

```cs
public IActionResult MyPage(string id = null)
{
    DoUserStuff(id);

    // Page related functionality 

    return View(myPageViewModel);
}
```

I'm struggling with the notion this helper method might need to return a redirect or the `id` and `employee` since those variables would be used in the actual meat of the controller.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: Do some research on "authorization attributes in asp.net core"

Comment: How are you setting `_currentUser` in the first place? I'm guessing in the constructor which means you're doing too much there. I would suggest you look into filter attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is *authorization*. The instinct to try and refactor your code is good, but in this case you should take note of the facilities the framework offers for solving this problem and find out how to take advantage of them. The result will not just be DRYer, it will involve a lot less code to begin with and will be more idiomatic and familiar to other ASP.NET Core developers.

The docs are pretty good in this area - I'd suggest these, in this order:

- [Authz overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [Simple authz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and more generally [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
- [Resource-based authz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (where access depends on the data, not just the action)

It's a lot to take in if you're new, but the investment is worth it.